# Internal graphics not initialized yet: javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm trying to write a `javaFx` application whit multiple images inside a window.

The short story is that I have an `enum` class named `Candy` and each candy has some properties and a path to the image file representing it.

In the constructor of my `javafx.application` class (`Table`) I want to fill an array list with those images, so I wrote this so far:

```
public class Table extends Application {

    ArrayList<Image> images;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("CandyFx");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Table() {
        images = new ArrayList<Image>();
        for (Candy candy : Candy.values()) {
            File file = new File (candy.getImagePath());
            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            images.add(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Now every time I want to create an instance of `Table` class, the application throws a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal graphics not initialized yet`.

How can I initial graphics which it seems I did not?

Comment: See related comments in the JavaFX issue tracker: [RT-30796 Cannot create a JavaFX Image until "Internal graphics" are initialized](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30796).

Comment: Also, you should never manually create an instance of the Table class (e.g. never write `new Table()`).  The Table instance will be created by the Java launcher - see the [JavaFX Application documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) for details on JavaFX Application lifecycle.  Also note that [a JavaFX Application cannot be launched more than once](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-).

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you. but what if I want to have some special methods in my application (like a method changing position of something on screen) that I want to be called from another function? (because I can not call the method on my created instance)

Comment: call methods which interact with the scene graph on the JavaFX application thread once the application start method has been invoked.

Answer (score 5):

First of all if you are using linux ,GTK 2.18 is required to run JavaFX .try to install

```
libswt-gtk-3-java
```

This exception will thrown whenever your screen is null .Try to create your images inside `start` method. Just before the `primaryStage.show();`.

Take a look at this link too

http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~vadim/RT-33475/webrev.00/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/Screen.java.html

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how it exactly works, but when we first create a JFXPanel in our start we don't get the errors anymore.

```
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, JavaFX Stage class is the top level JavaFX container which should be constructed and modified on the JavaFX Application Thread.

Here you are using Stage class but have not embed JavaFx content into Swing application which may show you a 'java.lang.RuntimeException with message Internal graphics not initialized yet.

Here you may use-

`JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();`

Or you may use in this way too.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Swing And JavaFX");  
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();  
frame.add(jfxPanel);
```

JFXPanel is a component to embed JavaFX content into Swing applications. The content to be displayed is specified with the setScene(javafx.scene.Scene) method that accepts an instance of JavaFX Scene. After the scene is assigned, it gets repainted automatically. All the input and focus events are forwarded to the scene transparently to the developer.

References:

```
    JFXPanel: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html

    Stage: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html
```